FullCalendar why event still overlap even though I set eventOverlap={false} and selectOverlap={false}
I am making a calendar to show even, event still overlap even though I set eventOverlap={false} selectOverlap={false} I try to figure out what wrong happen but cannot. please help me.
below is code of calendar and it css:


           <div className="two-columns">
                <div className="calendar">
                    <FullCalendar
                        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
                        initialView="dayGridMonth"
                        weekends={true}
                        // direction="rtl"
                        height={"auto"}
                        eventBorderColor="#EEF2F6"
                        dateClick={handleDateClick}
                        eventContent={renderEventContent}
                        datesSet={handleMonthChange}
                        eventOverlap={false}
                        selectOverlap={false}
                        // duration={}
                        events={[
                            ...listLunnarDate,
                            // { title: 'event 1', date: '2024-04-05' },
                            { title: 'event 2', date: '2024-04-04', overlap: false },
                            { title: 'event 2', date: '2024-04-04', overlap: false },
                            { title: 'event 2', date: '2024-04-04', overlap: false },

                        ]}
                    />
                </div>
                <div></div>
            </div>

.two-columns > * { /* Equal-width columns */
    padding: 1rem;
    display: flex;
}

.calendar {
    width: 70%;
}

/* Media query for mobile screens */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .two-columns {
        flex-direction: column; /* Stack columns vertically */
    }
    .calendar{
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.fc .fc-col-header-cell-cushion {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px; 
}
.fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner {
    border-top: none;
}

.fc-col-header-cell-cushion {
    font-weight: 400;
}
/* Custom CSS to override FullCalendar styles */
.fc-daygrid-event, .fc-event-title {
    text-align: left !important;
}

.fc .fc-daygrid-day-frame{
    height: 6rem;
}

I search in fullcalendar.io and some stackoverflow especially Is there a way to prevent overlapping events in jQuery FullCalendar? question but cannot find the answer

Can we just clarify your expectations on this? You haven't given a clear description of your problem, or a specific example of what you mean. I would emphasise that the eventOverlap setting controls whether you are allowed to drag an event on top of another event or not. And selectOverlap controls whether you are allowed to make a new event which is over the top of an existing one, or not.

I can't tell from your question whether you are having a problem with the processes of dragging and creating events, or whether you just didn't read the documentation properly and are expecting those settings to control the visual display of events when they are being rendered (i.e. to stop them overlapping in the initial display, when their start/end dates intersect). If that's the problem you're having then you need to use the slotEventOverlap setting. I think the documentation is fairly clear about what these settings are used for?

I have error when trying to set homogeneous size for all day(cause when a day have event size will expanded. And I dont want it happen, but when I set fixed size, if I have more event to render it overlap to bottom of screen. I dont know how to fix it so I decided to set only render 1 event in a day. thank for your help.

It sounds like you're trying to mess with fullCalendar's rendering, which is never a good idea - it builds the event grid and then layers the events on top of them, so it relies on precise positioning. If you mess with the size of events, by using your own CSS or whatever, then there's a good chance you will cause the display to go wrong due to positioning issues.  I don't know why you care about the all-day events being the same size, it wouldn't be a big issue - so what if the display expands? It should have space to show all the info, don't you think?
